# Point on a plane perpendicular to a line

Tags: vectors

This is from a quiz I recently took. I don't have the solutions.

Problem:

A plane $P$ contains the point $Q= (4,3,2)$ and is perpendicular to the line $r(t) = \langle3t, 5t, 7t\rangle$.
What should the value of $b$ for point $R =(3,b,-1)$ be  so that is lies on the same plane as point $Q$?

Hint: Find the direction vector for line $r(t)$

I'm not sure how to find the direction vector for line $r(t)$. Would this be a start?

$$\langle4,3,2\rangle \cdot n = 0$$

And then finding the normal vector $n$

Comment: I edited my solution to be more clear isn't it? if you face any problem with it just let me know

Comment: @Semsem Thank you, you're explanation was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you have
$$(R-Q).N=0\\
(-1,b-3,-3).(3,5,7)=0$$
The direction vector of a line is $v$ where $$r(t)=r(0)+tv$$
so you get the coefficients of $t$. Not that in your case $r(0)=(0,0,0)$. also you have to note that the direction vector of the line is the normal vector to the plane

Answer (score 0):

So the line is a normal to the plane, and thus the plane of of the form $3x+5y+7z=d$ Substitute Q in the equation to find $d$. Substitute R to find your $b$